# Throttling(reducing) the database insert speed in spring application

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-batch, jtds

I am working on a spring batch application where I am migrating millions or records from source db to destination db. While inserting the records into destination database, I am doing it in bulk inserts (1000 in each batch) and this way it inserts 3000 approx in a second.

destination db type - MS SQL server 2012, 
JDBC driver - JTDS

Now, I have a requirement where I should be able to reduce(not improve) the performance of the migration rate say 1000 records in 1 sec instead of inserting 3000. Is there a straight forward way to do this either using JDBC driver or any other configuration in spring?

Thanks,

Comment: Just some ideas, can you: 1. Remove an index 2. Use Insert statements instead 3. Decrease network bandwidth 4. Increase network latency (VPN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Guava's [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).

It's pretty simple. Instantiate it somewhere (probably as a Spring bean):

```
double CALLS_PER_SECOND = 100;

RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(CALLS_PER_SECOND);
```

Then use it in your loops:

```
rateLimiter.acquire();
```

You can't really do records/second, but you can do bytes/second or calls/second.

Answer (score 2):

Believe me, it's much easier to reduce the performance than to improve the performance.
For Spring batch application, the easiest way is to sleep a while in your ItemWriter implementation for example.

Answer (score 0):

Query Governor is similar to the limit option in Oracle: [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191219(v=sql.105).aspx)

Resource Governor allows you to set the min and max memory for the server: [Link2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180797(v=sql.105).aspx)